# How to express $y = 6\sin x\cos 3x + 6\cos x\sin 3x - 3$ in the form $y = A\sin Bx + D$, where $A$, $B$, and $D$ are constants

Tags: trigonometry

Express $y = 6\sin x\cos 3x + 6\cos x\sin 3x - 3$ in the form $y = A\sin Bx + D$, where $A$, $B$, and $D$ are constants.

Comment: Did you mean $y = A\sin Bx + D$?  Otherwise, $B$ will not be a constant.

Comment: A suggestion, to avoid being downvoted, or even getting your question closed, is to provide some insights of your own. Let us know precisely what parts you have difficulties understanding, and what you have tried so far. This helps people locate, in detail, what you need clarified. If you don't want to learn, or you just feel frustated and need an answer right away, (we've all been there at times) use http://www.wolframalpha.com instead.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
y&=6(\sin x \cos 3x+ \sin 3x \cos x)-3 \\
&=6(\sin(x+3x))-3 \\
&=6\sin 4x+(-3) \end{align}
Therefore $A=6 \\B=4
 \\ D=-3$.